# Alerta funciona de imediato caso o tempo seja superior ao alarm defenido

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

**Este é o codigo que tenho :**

```
  alarme.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, horas, 86400000, alarmIntent);
```

O objectivo era mandar uma notificação passadas 24 horas e funciona passadas 24 horas o problema é que imaginemos o meu alarme é para as 12:20 e eu quando disparo o alarme são 13:20 no meu sistema ele dispara o alarme logo, alguem sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é o [comportamento esperado](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set) do AlarmManager.

A solução passa por verificar, antes de criar o alarme, se a hora é anterior à hora actual e, se sim, acrescentar um dia.

Para facilitar "as contas" vamos usar a classe [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
//Cria um Calendar para a hora do alarme
Calendar horaAlarme = Calendar.getInstance();
//Seta a hora do alarme
horaAlarme.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
//Seta os minutos do alarme
horaAlarme.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
//Coloca zero nos segundos
horaAlarme.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

//Cria um Calendar com a data/hora actual
Calendar horaActual = Calendar.getInstance();

//Adiciona um dia caso a hora actual for superior à do alarme(12:20)
if(horaActual.getTimeInMillis() >= horaAlarme.getTimeInMillis()){
    horaAlarme.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}

//Agenda o Alarme
alarme.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    horaAlarme.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, 
                    alarmIntent);
```